# How to capture a group only if occurs twice in a line

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

text = """
Tumble Trouble Twwixt Two Towns!
Was the Moon soon in the Sea
Or soon in the sky?
Nobody really knows YET.
"""
```

[image]

How should I make the match happen only when the occurence is found twice in a line?

Regular expression that highlights two 'o's that appear beside each other only if there is another occurence of two 'o's appearing beside each other subsequently in the same line

Comment: You probably have to insert "anyting" before the repeated group, i.e. `(\w+).*\1`. Do you want to match any repeated elements, or only repeated repeated chars? I.e. should `the` in the second line also be a match?

Comment: Thank you for replying quickly I want the output to be something like this


Tumble Trouble Twwixt Two Towns!
Was the M{oo}n soon in the Sea
Or soon in the sky?
Nobody really knows YET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match a single word char with a backreference, and group that again.

The word character will become group 2 as the groups are nested, then the outer group will be group 1.

Then you can assert group 1 using a positive lookahead again in the line.

```
((\w+)\2)(?=.*?\1)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(\w+)\2` Match 1+ word chars in capture **group 2** followed by a backreference to group 2 to match the same again
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?=.*?\1)` Positive lookahead to assert the captured value of group 1 in the line

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C2hCvO/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/zNJDi2).

Example

```
print(re.compile(r"((\w+)\2)(?=.*?\1)").sub('{\g<1>}', text.rstrip()))
```

Output

```
Tumble Trouble Twwixt Two Towns!
Was the M{oo}n soon in the Sea
Or soon in the sky?
Nobody really knows YET.
```